# Spark SQL - DataFrame - How to read different format date format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Data set look like this. stuck in changing `HIRE_DATE` format to date format field

```
EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID
100,Steven,King,SKING,515.123.4567,17-JUN-03,AD_PRES,24000, - , - ,90
101,Neena,Kochhar,NKOCHHAR,515.123.4568,21-SEP-05,AD_VP,17000, - ,100,90
```

And code snippet

```
    val empData = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").
   csv(filePath)empData.printSchema()
```

The `printSchema` output is giving string for `HIRE_DATE` field . But i am expecting `Dateformat` field. How can I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way I do it :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy")

def convertStringToDate(StringDate:String) = {
    val parsed = dateFormat.parse(StringDate)
    new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime())
} 

val convertStringToDateUDF = udf(convertStringToDate _)

df.withColumn("HIRE_DATE",convertStringToDateUDF($"HIRE_DATE"))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. what is udf here. what is the purpose we are doing. df.withColumn("HIRE_DATE",convertStringToDateUDF($"HIRE_DATE")) - here we are re assigning the value or creating new value kind of hire_date_1 in oracle

Comment: is Hive UDF and Spark SQL UDF same ?

Comment: udf = User Defined Function (https://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/08/10/guide-to-writing-hive-udfs.html). We are creating a new column that will be, for each record, the output of the `convertStringToDate` applied to the record of $"HIRE_DATE". Because we create this column with a name that already exist in that dataframe, it will replace that old column by the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Spark has its own date type. If you supply the date value in the format string "yyyy-MM-dd", it can be converted to Spark's Date type. So all that you have to do is to bring the input date string to this format "yyyy-MM-dd"
And for time and date formatting, it is always better to use java.time libraries.
See below

```
  val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema",true).option("header", true).csv("in/emp2.txt")

  def formatDate(x:String):String =
  {
   val y = x.toLowerCase.split('-').map(_.capitalize).mkString("-")
   val z= java.time.LocalDate.parse(y,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy"))
   z.toString
  }
  val myudfDate = udf ( formatDate(_:String):String )
  val df2 = df.withColumn("HIRE_DATE2", date_format(myudfDate('HIRE_DATE),"yyyy-MM-dd") )
  df2.show(false)


+-----------+----------+---------+--------+------------+---------+-------+------+--------------+----------+-------------+----------+
|EMPLOYEE_ID|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|EMAIL   |PHONE_NUMBER|HIRE_DATE|JOB_ID |SALARY|COMMISSION_PCT|MANAGER_ID|DEPARTMENT_ID|HIRE_DATE2|
+-----------+----------+---------+--------+------------+---------+-------+------+--------------+----------+-------------+----------+
|100        |Steven    |King     |SKING   |515.123.4567|17-JUN-03|AD_PRES|24000 | -            | -        |90           |2003-06-17|
|101        |Neena     |Kochhar  |NKOCHHAR|515.123.4568|21-SEP-05|AD_VP  |17000 | -            |100       |90           |2005-09-21|
+-----------+----------+---------+--------+------------+---------+-------+------+--------------+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: let me check and execute your code snippet. BTW df2.show(false)? i know df2.show() ,

Comment: without (false), the results may truncate in the console like "NKOCHA...", with (false), all the columns will be expanded to show all data

Comment: thanks a lot.. working fine as expected. did some changes in above code for convert sting to date object. empData.withColumn("HIRE_DATE1", date_format(dateFormatConversionUDF(($"HIRE_DATE")), "yyyy-MM-dd").cast("date")).. correct me if am  wrong

Comment: yes right..just assign it to another "df" and check using printSchema